# How can I find the coordinates of the circumference of a circle that rotates around the circumference of another circle?

Tags: java, user-interface, geometry, trigonometry

```
public static void drawSpiral(Display panel) {
    int centerX = panel.getWidth() / 2;
    int centerY = panel.getHeight() / 2;

    double degAng = 270;
    double radius = 150;
    double x, y, radAng;
    while ( true ) {

        radAng = ( degAng * Math.PI ) / 180;
        x = centerX + radius * Math.cos ( radAng );
        y = centerY + radius * Math.sin ( radAng );

        panel.drawNextPoint ( (int) x, (int) y );
        degAng += 0.45;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a method that uses a simple GUI that draws. The method as it is above draws the coordinates of a simple circle with radius 150 starting from the top. I am trying to draw a circle that uses the point given by this method as its center point.

This is what I've tried most recently and it only gives me an ellipse!

```
public static void drawCircle(Display panel) {
    int centerX = panel.getWidth() / 2;
    int centerY = panel.getHeight() / 2;

    double degAng = 270;
    double newDegAng = 0;
    double newRadius = 25;
    double radius = 150;
    double x, y, radAng, newX, newY, newRadAng;
    while ( true ) {

        radAng = ( degAng * Math.PI ) / 180;
        x = centerX + radius * Math.cos ( radAng );
        y = centerY + radius * Math.sin ( radAng );

        newRadAng = (newDegAng * Math.PI) / 180;
        newX =  x - newRadius * Math.cos (newRadAng);
        newY =  y - newRadius * Math.sin (newRadAng);

        panel.drawNextPoint ( (int) newX, (int) newY );
        degAng += 0.45;
        newDegAng -= 0.45;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your circle to exhaustion before you get to the next point. So you will need a nested loop:

```
double degAng = 0;
double newDegAng = 0;
double newRadius = 25;
double radius = 150;
double x, y, radAng, newX, newY, newRadAng;
while ( degAng<360 ) {
    radAng = ( degAng * Math.PI ) / 180;
    x = centerX + radius * Math.cos ( radAng );
    y = centerY + radius * Math.sin ( radAng );

    newDegAng = 0;
    while ( newDegAng>-360 ) {
      newRadAng = (newDegAng * Math.PI) / 180;
      newX =  x - newRadius * Math.cos (newRadAng);
      newY =  y - newRadius * Math.sin (newRadAng);
      drawPoint ( (int) newX, (int) newY);
      newDegAng -= 0.45;
    }

    drawPoint( (int) x, (int) y );
    degAng += 0.45;
}
```

This creates a nice picture like this

[image]

This draws all the circles so it creates effectively a tube.